# How to display a ggplot figure when using Brew package in R? Keep getting error

Tags: r, ggplot2, markdown, r-brew

I am using the Brew package in R to create a markdown file with results from my analysis.

Using the Brew syntax, my code looks like:

```
<%= ggplot.hist %>
```

where ggplot.hist is my ggplot object.  However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

Brew seems to call the cat function, which cannot operate on a ggplot.

Hopefully that makes sense.  Has anyone been able to get a ggplot to work when using Brew?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `ggplot.hist` a plot object? I haven't used `brew` in years, but I think you might need to wrap plot objects in `print()`. Or maybe that was `Sweave`...

Comment: Give a try to my "fork" that would automatically `print` what's needed to be printed (and saved to an image file): http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#brew-to-pandoc